# how is this picture made?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting, adobe-photoshop-elements

Good day guys,
i have to something like this,
any idea how is this picture made ? 
so it looks like negative i did invert it in photoshop but the bright side of his face was blue, so there been negative effect and smting been used to change his face to blue before nagative or smting that changed his face to normal skin color after negative ? what can it be ? what do you guys think ? THANKS ! for help.

[image]

Comment: I would assume it's two layers -- one that's inverted and one that's not. Then they are combined either via blending modes or masking.

Answer (score 6):

That is basicly a simple Inverted solarization.

On Photoshop

**1)** Open Curves (Ctrl+M)

**2)** Use a U shaped curve.

(The normal solarization is an inverted U shape)

[image]

But of course you can prepare some masking to controll the result.

If the case I would prepare a mask

- Copying the image.
- Pasting it into a new layer mask.
- Moving curves.